# Remove tool tip from warning dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, tooltip, hide

I want to remove YES and NO tool tip from a custom dialog box after the dialog is displayed.
The problem is that I am unable to get the object of the YES and NO buttons by ID or attribute name due to not being able to remove the "title" attribute".

Here is what the customDialog function looks like

```
function dialog_customDialog(dialogType, callingWindow,msg, showThird, firstCBF, secondCBF, thirdCBF, firstText, secondText, thirdText, dialogTimeout, timeoutCBF) {
    if (dialogTimeout > 0) {
        yesCallback = function() {processCallback(firstCBF);};
        noCallback = function() {processCallback(secondCBF);};
        cancelCallback = function() {processCallback(thirdCBF);};
    }
    else {
        yesCallback = firstCBF;
        noCallback = secondCBF;
        cancelCallback = thirdCBF;
    }

    timeoutCallback = timeoutCBF

    if (showThird)
        buttonSet = 3;
    else
        buttonSet = 2;

    if (firstText) {
        var ybt = document.getElementById('button_YES');
        if (ybt) {
            if (!yesText) yesText = ybt.innerHTML;
            ybt.innerHTML = firstText;
        }
    }

    if (secondText) {
        var nbt = document.getElementById('button_NO');
        if (nbt) {
            if (!noText) noText = nbt.innerHTML;
            nbt.innerHTML = secondText;
        }
    }

    if (thirdText) {
        var cbt = document.getElementById('button_CANCEL');
        if (cbt) {
            if (!cancelText) cancelText = cbt.innerHTML;
            cbt.innerHTML = thirdText;
        }
    }
    if(!dialogType) {
        displayDialog(callingWindow,msg, 'questImg', 'Question',buttonSet,firstText,secondText,thirdText,dialogTimeout);
    }
    else if('warning' == dialogType.toLowerCase()){
        displayDialog(callingWindow,msg, 'warnImg', 'Warning',buttonSet,firstText,secondText,thirdText,dialogTimeout);
    }
    else if('information' == dialogType.toLowerCase()){
        displayDialog(callingWindow,msg, 'infoImg', 'Information',buttonSet,firstText,secondText,thirdText,dialogTimeout);
    }
    else if('information' == dialogType.toLowerCase()){
         displayDialog(callingWindow,msg, 'errorImg', 'Error',buttonSet,firstText,secondText,thirdText,dialogTimeout);
    }
    else{
        displayDialog(callingWindow,msg, 'questImg', 'Question',buttonSet,firstText,secondText,thirdText,dialogTimeout);
    }
}
```

After the dialog is displayed i am trying to hide the tool tip. Here is the code.

```
var yesBtn=  $("#button_YES");
yesBtn.removeAttr("title");
```

The problem is yesBtn object is empty. Here is how the HTML code for the dialog button looks like:

[image]